# wrong linking point with lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't know what I'm missing but I cannot figure out a very simple task. This is a small piece of my dataframe:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "SOU55", class = "factor"), Depth = c(2L, 4L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L), Value = c(211.8329815, 
278.9603866, 255.6111086, 212.6163368, 193.7281895, 200.9584658, 
160.9289157, 192.0664419, 174.5951019, 7.162682425)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Depth", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

What I'm trying to do is simply plotting Depth versus Value with ggplot, this is the simple code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Value, Depth))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

and this the result:

[image]

But it is pretty different from what I really want. This is the plot made with Libreoffice:

[image]

It seems that ggplot doesn't link correctly the values. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Wrong `geom`. Just use `geom_path()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `geom_path()` to connect the observations in the original order. `geom_line()` sorts the data according to the `x`-aesthetic before plotting:

`ggplot(df, aes(Value, Depth))+
     geom_point()+
     geom_path()`

Comment: ahrrrrrrr.. that's it! Thanks!